# $T:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$, linear, diagonal with respect to any basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$ which is represented by a diagonal matrix when written with respect to any fixed basis?

If such linear transformation $T$ exists, then its eigenvector should be the identity matrix for any fixed basis $\beta$ of $\Bbb R^2$.
Then, I don't see, if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $T$ is diagonal in at least one basis, $T$ has two eigenvalues $a$ and $b$ and two linearly independent eigenvectors $x$ and $y$ such that $Tx=ax$ and $Ty=by$.

If $a\ne b$, $x+y$ is not an eigenvector hence the matrix of $T$ in the basis $(x+y,y)$ is not diagonal. This is absurd. Hence, $a=b$, that is, $T=aI$.

In the other direction, if $T=aI$ for some $a$, then its matrix in any basis is diagonal.

Comment: Way to go, Did. +1

Answer (score 8):

If $T$ is diagonal with respect to any basis, then every nonzero vector is an eigenvector, since any nonzero vector can be extended to a basis. Then it must be that the whole vector space is one eigenspace corresponding to the same eigenvalue, since if two vectors were eigenvectors with *different* eigenvalues, then the sum would not be an eigenvector. Since any matrix acts on an eigenspace $E$ as $\lambda I$, then it follows $T = \lambda I$, where $\lambda$ is some scalar.

So the identity matrix works, but so does any multiple of the identity.

Comment: How do you prove your first claim?

Comment: Every vector can be extended to a basis, and by assumption every basis is a basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: Yes. Maybe you could add this sentence to your answer? (every nonzero vector, btw) Just a suggestion, of course. Note that "then it must be" is not transparent for everyone either.

Comment: This is certainly more elegant than my answer, but I figured a pedestrian calculation would be nice to see, too.

Answer (score 2):

If the transformation $T$ is represented by the matrix $A$ in basis $\mathcal{A}$, then it is represented by the matrix $PAP^{-1}$ in basis $\mathcal{B}$, where $P$ is the invertible change-of-basis matrix.

Suppose that $T$ is represented by a diagonal matrix in *any* basis.  Let $P$ be an arbitrary invertible matrix and $A$ any diagonal matrix:

$$P = \left[\begin{array}{cc} p_{1,1} & p_{1,2} \\ p_{2,1} & p_{2,2} \end{array}\right] \text{ and } A = \left[\begin{array}{cc} d_1 & 0 \\ 0 & d_2 \end{array}\right].$$

Now, calculate

$PAP^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{\det P} \left[\begin{array}{cc} b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} \\ b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} \end{array}\right]$, where the entries $b_{i,j}$ are polynomials in the $p_{i,j}$ and $d_i$ variables.

For this new conjugated matrix to be diagonal, we have the following two equations.  (Check!)

$$\begin{align*}
0 = b_{1,2} &= (d_2 - d_1)p_{1,1}p_{1,2} \\
0 = b_{2,1} &= (d_1 - d_2)p_{2,1}p_{2,2}
\end{align*}$$

Since $P$ is arbitrary, the only way for these equations to *always* be satisfied is for $d_1 = d_2$.  In other words, the original matrix $A$ was a scalar multiple of the identity.

$$A = d \cdot \operatorname{Id}_2 = \left[\begin{array}{cc} d & 0 \\ 0 & d \end{array}\right].$$

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**:
More generally:
let $R$ be a unital ring, then the for a matrix $Z\in M_{n\times n}(R)$ the following are equivalent:

1. is invariant with respect to any chosen basis of $R^n$
2. $Z$ is representable as a diagonal matrix in some basis of $R^n$.
3. $Z$ is a scalar matrix, ie: $\left( (\exists r \in R) Z=rI_n \right)$
4. $Z$ is in the center of $GL_n(R)$.

*Proof (assuming 4 $\Leftrightarrow 2$ which can be found in a text on algebraic groups, or affine group schemes):*

Any element $Z$ of the center of $M_{n\times n}(R)$ then satisfies:

\begin{equation}
(\forall P \in GL_n(R)) \mbox{ } Z= IZ=PP^{-1}Z = PZ P^{-1}.  
\end{equation}

However, since the center of $M_{n\times n}(R)$ is the diagonal subgroup of $GL_n(R)$ and since any change of basis of $R^n$ is the same as conjugating by some $P\in GL_n(R)$.

Therefore a matrix is the same under any basis of $R^n$ if and only if it is invariant with respect to any conjugation by some $P\in GL_n(R)$ if and only if it is in the center of $GL_n(R)$ if and only if it is diagonal is some basis if and only if its is a scalar matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: it's the identity transformation $Tx = x$.

Comment: What about `T=42.I`?